# Windows10: Having issues installing ROS2 Iron Irwini 20230717 release binary

Tags: ros, ros2

I'm a complete newbie to ROS. I followed the steps listed on this page very meticulously:

https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html#

But when I run the command call `C:\dev\ros2_iron\local_setup.bat` I get the message:

`"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."`

I don't understand this message. I never changed the default DDS, and the docs page says Fast DDS is the default, so why is the setup looking for RTI Connext DDS??

Also, some steps on the docs page are not fully written out in all details.

For example, under "Install miscellaneous prerequisites",

- Next install xmllint:

- Download the 64 bit binary archives of libxml2(and its dependencies iconv and zlib) from https://www.zlatkovic.com/projects/libxml/
- Unpack all archives into e.g. C:\xmllint
- Add `C:\xmllint\bin` to the PATH.

Unpacking all archives into the folder creates 3 separate subfolders with individual bin folders. So, then there is no `C:\xmllint\bin` folder to add to the PATH. What do they mean to say? Am I supposed to combine all the files under each bin folder from the subfolders and create a new bin folder `C:\xmllint\bin` ?

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I just can't get it set up properly. Would really appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 1):

> `"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."`

This is a usual **warning** while sourcing in Windows which tells to include path to **Connext DDS** in `PATH` system variable in case you are using connext DDS. If you are using **fast DDS or cyclone DDS**, ignore this warning. This does not affect you system unless Connext DDS is used.

Comment: But ignoring doesn't help. I cannot launch ROS. Running the local_setup.bat file is supposed to launch ROS.

Comment: That sounds like you have incorrect expectations of what local_setup.bat will do. Please ask a new question and make sure to explain what you're doing, what you're getting and what you expect. Highlight what's different and what you've tried to do to resolve it. This forum is best if you ask one question at a time. And it's important to give enough background to avoid XY problems.